# Can a non-copyable member be used as alternative to make an object non-copyable?

Tags: c++, c++11

A class with non-copyable member is said to be also non-copyable. From SO, to make a class non-copyable these are the options:

1. Use boost::noncopyable
2. Declare constructor and assignment operator as private.
3. Delete copy constructor.

   ```
   class foo 
   {
       private:
         std::mutex _dummy;
   };
   ```

Question: Will inclusion of a dummy non-copyable member be used for similar purpose and for simplicity? What are the down-sides?

Comment: You tagged this question C++11. Is there some reason why you can't just `= delete` the copy constructor?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Thanks I add that.

Comment: "Will inclusion of a dummy non-copyable member be used for similar purpose and for simplicity? What are the down-sides?" - No, isn't enough. You can write a copy constructor that do nothing about it.

Comment: Always say what you mean - adding a non-copyable object (particularly something like a mutex) simply obfuscates your code. Simply delete the copy constructor and probably assignment operator.

Comment: @max66 Yes, it is enough, it's just not desirable.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - Maybe I should say "isn't sufficient"... I mean: one can write a class with a non-copyable element and a copy-constructor that doesn't copy the value of it. So the object is copyable and contain a non-copyable member. I know: silly. For the same reason make the copy constructor, and `operator=()` `private`, isn't sufficient because you can make a function `friend` to the class and the class become copyable (inside the `friend` function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++11, the proper idiom for making a class non-copyable is to `= delete` the copy constructor/assignment operator. That's what C++ programmers are told to do, and that's what other C++ programmers will expect to see when looking for that behavior in your class..

It's fine to have a subobject (member or base class) that is non-copyable, and thus your default copy constructor/assignment operator will be implicitly deleted. But you should only do this for a subobject that *happens to be* non-copyable. That is, you have a `unique_ptr<T>` or `mutex` or whatever as a member because you *need* a `unique_ptr<T>` or a `mutex` as class instance data. Not because you're using it as a hack to make the type non-copyable.

The downsides of using a member subobject for this purpose are:

1. It muddles the meaning of your code. Your `mutex _dummy;` example tells me that your type has a `mutex` in it. If nothing ever uses that variable, then that tells me that your code is rather incoherent; if you don't need a subobject, you don't declare one. `= delete` is the proper idiom, so it is what you should use.
2. `boost::noncopyable` was the C++98/03 idiom because it was an empty class. And thus, common empty base optimization would ensure that it wouldn't take up any space in the derived class. Empty members get no such optimization, so a member `boost::noncopyable` will always make your class bigger, to no advantage. And while you could point to the upcoming C++20 `[[no_unique_address]]` attribute, see reason #1.